# Property does not exist on type within Redux reducer using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to use Redux with TypeScript in a little learning project, following this tutorial:
https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/

```
const INITIAL_STATE: TweetsState = {
  tweets: []
};

const tweetsReducer: Reducer<TweetsState> = (
  state = INITIAL_STATE,
  action: TweetAction
): TweetsState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TWEETS:
      return {
        ...state
      };

    case TWEETS_RECEIVED:
      return {
        tweets: [...state.tweets, action.payload]
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My reducer expects an action of type TweetAction, which is the union of two interfaces:

```
export interface IGetTweetsAction {
  type: typeof GET_TWEETS;
}

export interface ITweetsReceivedAction {
  type: typeof TWEETS_RECEIVED;
  payload: ITweet[];
}

export const GET_TWEETS: string = "GET_TWEETS";
export const TWEETS_RECEIVED: string = "TWEETS_RECEIVED";

export type TweetAction = IGetTweetsAction | ITweetsReceivedAction;
```

However, within my reducer, I get the error `Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'TweetAction'` which is confusing because it suggests the union hasn't worked?

But this is further confusing because within my actions file it clearly allows me to return an object, of type TweetAction, with a payload:

```
import {
  TweetAction,
  GET_TWEETS,
  TWEETS_RECEIVED,
  ITweet
} from "./tweets.types";

export const getTweets = (): TweetAction => ({
  type: GET_TWEETS
});

export const tweetsReceived = (tweets: ITweet[]): TweetAction => ({
  type: TWEETS_RECEIVED,
  payload: tweets
});
```

I'm aware the code is currently a bit of a mess (I sometimes instinctively prefix interfaces with I being a C# dev, sorry!) as I haven't been through a refactory stage yet as I'm just trying to whip something up quickly, but I've been stumped by this error.

Can anyone see what's going wrong? It's probably something straight forward but the isolation might be getting to my head.

Thanks!

Edit: Note that removing the typesafety and changing:
`action: TweetAction` to just `action` allows me to do `action.payload` and the functionality works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- edit -----

Ok So apparently you need to remove the `: string` typing in those lines:

```
export const GET_TWEETS: string = "GET_TWEETS";
export const TWEETS_RECEIVED: string = "TWEETS_RECEIVED";
```

-- /edit -----

I'm pretty new to typescript too, but as I understand it, since you use `action.payload` in your reducer, the type `TweetAction` is not accepted since it could imply a `IGetTweetsAction` type, which does not define a `payload` property.

You need to use a more generic type like:
`type TweetAction {
  type: // ...,
}`

to say that you can have an action that will always have a `type` and might have some other props (such as a `payload`).

As for your confusing example, I think that actually makes sense:

```
export const getTweets = (): TweetAction => ({
  type: GET_TWEETS
});
```

No `payload` is defined so it matches `IGetTweetsAction`.

```
export const tweetsReceived = (tweets: ITweet[]): TweetAction => ({
  type: TWEETS_RECEIVED,
  payload: tweets
});
```

While this one matches `ITweetsReceivedAction`.

Comment: Whilst I get what you're saying, the example that can be found here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/ shows a scenario where a ChatActionTypes can contain both a payload or a meta timestamp and that it works fine using the union operator as I have tried to do. This could be where some concepts differ between TypeScript and how interfaces operate in other languages perhaps?

Comment: I found that it works on the redux doc because they don't specify a `: string` on the constants `SEND_MESSAGE` for example. Basically this works: `export const SEND_MESSAGE = 'SEND_MESSAGE'`, but this does not `export const SEND_MESSAGE: string = 'SEND_MESSAGE'`
No idea why, though :/

Comment: You can test it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-blackburn-hv1pv

Comment: You've cracked it, it was the strings! Yeah, I have no idea why this makes a difference too. But what matters is that it works now. Thanks for the help Nicolas :) If you want to edit your initial answer with an edit at the bottom containing the tip to change the strings, happy to select it as the correct answer that'll help your karma!

Comment: I've edited my post. I'd really like an explanation of why defining the type with a `typeof [SOME_CONSTANT]` and not typing those constants, rather than `type: string` work...

Comment: Agreed, so would I! But I think at this point I'm also very new to TypeScript and whilst I think it's starting to grow on me, it certainly does still baffle me in places (most likely due to my own shortcomings!).